# No funciona printf luego de recibir informacion del scanf en lenguaje C

Tags: c, scanf, printf

estoy recién aprendiendo a utilizar el lenguaje C.
Creando un nuevo programa que es como una calculadora me surge el siguiente problema: Recibe los 2 números iniciales por consola pero al instante de recibir el segundo número el programa se cierra y no me muestra para nada los resultados.
Uso Windows 10, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.
Este es el código:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int operando1, operando2;
    printf("Introduce 2 numeros enteros\n");
    printf("Numero 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &operando1);
    printf("Numero 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &operando2);
    
    printf("Resultado:\n");
    
    printf("Suma: %d\n", operando1 + operando2);
    printf("Resta: %d\n", operando1 - operando2);
    printf("Multiplicación: %d\n", operando1 * operando2);
    printf("División(cociente): %d\n", operando1 / operando2);
    printf("División(resto): %d\n", operando1 % operando2);
    printf("\n\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente, solo que es normal que luego de la ejecución del programa la consola se cierre. Agrégale una o dos líneas de  `getchar();` al final para que quede esperando por una tecla. Puedes hacer también un `scanf` de alguna tecla en específica para esperar a que no se cierre.

Comment: Si estás en windows, puedes agregar al final antes del return  `system("pause");`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó con el system("pause");

Comment: No uses la función `system("pause")` para pausar la ejecución del programa, usa la función `getchar()`, es mas portable.